# photo on the side of the text

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to make the text on the page have a photo next to

using flex.
I managed to do something like that, I couldn't find your way
https://codepen.io/Kxamil/pen/OJJBRLR


It must look like this

and next to the text the picture

```
        <main class="main-aboutus">
        <div class="about">
            <div class="aboutimg">
                <img class="aboutusimg" src="./images/buiten.png" alt="">
            <!-- </div> -->
            <h3 class="head-about">Over Ons</h3>
            <p class="desc-about">Fritz De Meyer uit Kaprijke, is de specialist bij uitstek voor alle binnen- en
                buitenschilderwerken.
                Schilderwerken De Meyer werkt met kwalitatieve producten om bij de klant een perfect resultaat te
                garanderen. U als klant, kiest de graad van afwerking. Wij geven daarenboven steeds decoratieadvies
                U kunt ons steeds contacteren voor een vrijblijvende prijsofferte.
                Wij werken met Boss, Sikkens en Herbol
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

If is the about div to have display:flex, you just need to create 2 div inside it, and in the first one insert the text, and in the second one the image, display:flex will give around 50% each and align horizontally